# Remove quotation marks from all object string values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm currently reading data from a file which returns an array of values.
This is how the array in the file looks like:

```
"modules": [
     "console","fs"
     ]
```

After getting the data, I'm able to convert it to an object with both the key and the value having the same 'name' like this:

```
    var obj = modulesFile.modules.reduce(function (key,value) {
        key[value] = value;
        return key;

    },{})
```

This returns:

```
{console: "console", fs: "fs"}
```

Now the problem I have here is that, I don't want the quotation marks on the value, it can be on the key just fine but not the value. Something like this:

```
{"console": console, "fs": fs}
```

How do I go about something like this?

Comment: what is `fs` in `"fs": fs`?

Comment: Why do you think the quotation marks are actually there? How are you printing those values? Did you check the actual first and last characters?

Comment: it's node's file system

Comment: @rockstar don't really get your question. But on how I'm actually printing the values, using `console.log()` returns `{console: "console", fs: "fs"}`

Comment: How are you going to store text if you don't use quotes?

Comment: So then there are no quotation marks in the string values. You're just looking at a syntactic representation of data, much like you'd use when creating literals in a programming language. `var foo = "bar"` doesn't create a string with quotation marks in it. They're just delimiters.

Comment: It's not supposed to be a text. I'm trying to dynamically insert the object into node's vmContext. For example. `vm.runInNewContext('console.log(123)', {console})`

Comment: So you're saying you want a reference to the value of the `fs` variable, which is defined locally?

Comment: If they're all module it would've been easy: `key[value] = require(value);`. But I see `console` in there so...

Comment: @rockstar yes, something of that sort. Just that, I want a situation whereby, if the user specifies 'console' or 'fs' in the json file I'm reading from, the object in Context should be `{console}` or `{fs}` and if both specified, it should be `{console, fs}`

Comment: So yeah, you're trying to read a local variable but using a string for the variable name. You can search for answers since it gets asked quite a bit.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes you are right. The console doesn't work but say, the 'fs' works.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: `require('console')` doesn't work? Node has it defined as a module, but then I stopped using Node years ago, so I'm not up to date.